# Django channels can't use redis

Tags: django, redis

I am trying to do a chat app with Django channels. To do it I copied the code of a youtube video from Github. The video link is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLwu1NqU1rE). But when I run it I get `WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.`
I use redis.

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

But when I use `InMemoryChannelLayer` it works perfectly. Also I haven't enabled the Redis localhost. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: is `redis` running? check with `redis-cli ping`

Comment: no, it isn't running. Can you say how can I do it?

Comment: install redis on your machine and then run "redis-server" on command line

Comment: How can I install it?

Comment: check this https://developer.redis.com/create/windows/